# JQuery Validate Group of Radio Buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm using jquery's validator plugin to validate my entire form. And I have a set of radio buttons like this:

```
<div class="radio_options" style="display:none; margin-left:7px;">
    <label><input type="radio" name="options" value="1"> Option1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="options" value="2"> Option2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="options" value="3"> Option3</label>
</div>
```

I know I can just put

```
class="required"
```

But it displays the required message next to option 1 making it look like **that** radio button is required. Rather I want to display a *custom* message above all the radio buttons requiring at least one be selected.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$(".form").validate({
    ...
    ,errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if (element.is("input:radio")) {
            element.parents("div:first").before(error);
        } else {
            element.after(error);
        }
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: Ah okay, now how do I make a display a custom message?

Comment: @MichaelBenneton `... ,messages: {"options": "My error message"} ...`

Comment: @HalilÖzgür, How would you do it if you wanted the error label to appear **right between** the last `<label><input type="radio" name="options" value="3"> Option3</label>` and closing `</div>` tag? Thanks.

Comment: @Ricardo, `element.parents("div:first").append(error);` note the use of `append` instead of `before`.